# How can I use ReactJS as a static website?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to develop my static web application with React. I have just done with the [Tic-tac-toe getting started tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). Are there anyways I can "compile" (or whatever the term is) ReactJS straight into my HTML file? So, far to run that ReactJS application I need to run it with a server from Yarn.

I prefer to not use CDN because I want to update and manage the dependencies.

Let say, for my starting point, I want to have that Tic-tac-toe game from official React getting started tutorial to be served with just one HTML file (CSS and JS in that one HTML file). I want to see if this is possible or not, **so I don't care about the best practice** for this question.

Comment: Build the app then take the file output? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791069/create-react-app-npm-run-build-command

Comment: I think I miss something or I am not, idk. I have ran yarn build opened the index.html, but it returns this error: pastebin.com/RTLdhxPj.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [Gatsby JS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)

It's a static site generator for React. Probably that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm run build` or `yarn build` and see the output in the `build` folder. It generates static HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: I think I miss something or I am not, idk. I have ran `yarn build` opened the index.html, but it returns this error: https://pastebin.com/RTLdhxPj.

Comment: Try deploy it to a web server. Opening it through the file system may not work.

Comment: I want it to be static website. I don't want to use server. This can be done with CDN, but I would like to see if I can make static website with ReactJS downloaded from a package manager like Yarn or NPM.

Comment: You shouldn't need to deploy it to a web server.  You should be able to run it locally.

Comment: It is a static website. Something has to serve the static files over HTTP to the browser. Therefore you have to use a web server which serves *static* files.

Comment: Theoretically you could open the `index.html` and load the page from the file system. It could work, but often the browser doesn't allow you to load additional resources (security reasons) and the links in the page could be broken as well.

Comment: You could use a *local* web server as well, you don't need to deploy to a remote server or CDN. If you run `yarn start`, it starts a local lightweight web server and serves the static files over HTTP to the browser.

Comment: I have tested. `yarn build` works only with a server. Even `python3 -m http.server` works. So, no! ReactJS will not work without server out-of-the-box.

Comment: But it's not about ReactJS. It is just a client side framework. As I said before you need to serve HTML, CSS and Javascript to the browser over HTTP. This is why you need the server and not because ReactJS is dependent on it.

Comment: @DávidMolnár That's simply wrong. Your webbrowser can read from file:// without the need of a server (software).

Comment: @DarkTrick you're right. The browser can read files from the filesystem using `file://`, but it often leads to problems and in this case you might need to fix the URL's in the html and CSS files. That's why I'm suggesting to use a static web server in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using Yarn with `create-react-app`.  If so you are running:

`yarn start`

Now run:

`yarn build`

See more info here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

The static web application will be built to a `build` folder.  You will find all of the static assets there like JS, CSS and HTML.

Comment: I think I miss something or I am not, idk. I have ran `yarn build` opened the index.html, but it returns this error: https://pastebin.com/RTLdhxPj.

Comment: That is a different issue, perhaps best suited for a new question.  Link it here when created and we can help.

Comment: And these might help for that issue: 
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484183/cannot-create-react-app , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566235/how-to-generate-bundle-js-for-existing-react-app-created-using-create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

I have tested. `yarn build` works only with a server. Even `python3 -m http.server` works. So, no! ReactJS downloaded from non-Bower package manager will not work without server out-of-the-box.